# Ignore and Append tabs in worksheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

New to python/pandas... I get a profit and loss report from my trading brokerage in PDF. I can convert it into a spreadsheet that splits it up into headings on one worksheet and a table on another worksheet which it does for each page of the PDF report. I do this simply and cleanly for now just using export from Adobe PDF.

What I'm trying to figure out next is how to loop through the worksheet and ignore Tabs that have headings or data that does not match the columns of the Tabs that I want to append. I'm able to use this tutorial https://pythoninoffice.com/use-python-to-combine-multiple-excel-files/ for the most part, but I have no idea how to generalise the process so that over time as the report grows in PDF pages that I do not need to specify to pandas what number tabs to append and what number tabs to ignore, and can just run a loop in python until it runs out of tabs/worksheets to look at that match certain headers for appending.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

[Ignore the tabs with this Tab header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LwK3.png)

[Append tabs with this header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXRbU.png)

Comment: The link you shared already see how to get all the sheets in a spreadsheet. Yo need some logic to decide what sheets process, but there are no information in you question to help about that

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the fact that you only want sheets with more than one row, read all sheets, concat only the ones with more than one row, here goes:

```
import pandas as pd

# create sample data
df_many_lines = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]])
df_one_line = pd.DataFrame([10,20,30]).T

# create sample file
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    for i in range(10):
        df_one_line.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Sheet_name_{i}', index=False)
        df_many_lines.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Sheet_name_1{i}', index=False)

# read all the sheets to a dict of dfs
df_dict = pd.read_excel('output.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

# concat the ones with more than one row to one df
pd.concat([df for df in df_dict.values() if df.shape[0]>1]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: hey thank you, I'll fiddle with it and you've given me a place to work from

Answer (score 0):

I'm the original author of that tutorial you quoted at https://pythoninoffice.com

That's a lot of trades that you made! If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to:

1. Ignore tabs that contain only the header row, and
2. Append tabs that contain actual trade information

Since this is a p&l report, I'm assuming that all trade tabs (green tabs you highlighted) have the same format? Also, all the header (red) tabs contain the same format, i.e. only headers?

You can probably read all tabs and check if there's actually anything inside the dataframe. If not, you know it's a header (red) tab, otherwise, if there's data, then it's a trade (green) tab.

```
import pandas as pd

temp = pd.DataFrame()
with pd.ExcelFile('file_path') as excel:
    for sheet in excel.sheet_names:
        df = excel.parse(sheet)
        if not df.empty:
            temp = temp.append(df)
```

On a side note, to make your process more streamlined, you can try to use Python to convert a pdf to Excel instead of manually doing it in Adobe. https://pythoninoffice.com/pdf-to-excel-with-python/

Comment: Hey wow thanks so much! Yeah that was only one page of many and you are correct. Thanks for the pointer to the other tutorial as well your topics are really well structured